# Is is possible to use Ninject on an EntityFramework Entity object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to have a class that can be loaded and saved using Entity Framework which also uses Ninject to populate Interfaces with concrete implementations at run time.

I started with a constructor like this:

```
    public FancyObject(ICatProvider kitty)
    {
        this.kitty = kitty;
    }
```

This works as far as Ninject goes, we get a Cat - and it works for saving the entity to SQLServer using Entity Framework. However, it fails when trying to load the entity because Entity Framework needs a parameterless constructor.

So I tried putting it on a property like this:

```
    [Inject]
    public ICatProvider kitty { get; set; }

    public FancyObject()
    {
    }
```

This can load from the DB, but Kitty is always null.

All I have in the bindings is:

```
    kernel.Bind<ICatProvider>().To<FancyFileBasedCat>();
```

I'm guessing this is because I'm using the Entity Framework to create the entities and so Ninject isn't getting a look in.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is right. Your property is `null` because:

> "using the Entity Framework to create the entities and so Ninject isn't getting a look in."

However you can use the `Kernel.Inject` method ([wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns#initialization-methods)) to inject dependencies to existing instances:

```
var fancyObject = db.GetFancyObject();
kernel.Inject(fancyObject);
// fancyObject.kitty should be filled in.
```

Entities having dependencies usually is a code smell and maybe you should rethink your design. There are lots of way to avoid dependencies in entities like:

- Passing the service when it is needed:

  ```
  public class FancyObject
  {
       public Result MethodWorkingWithCats(int somearg, ICatProvider kitty)
       {
            reuturn DoSoemThing(this, somearg, kitty)
       }
  }
  ```
- Create a `FancyObjectService` which dependy on the `ICatProvider` and works on/with `FancyObject`
- etc.

Comment: Yes, it's probably not the most elegant design - needing to manually inject each instance feels really hacky - and that's only required  due to the smelly dependency. I think you're right - injecting it in at a higher level and then passing it into the entities as required might be the better solution. Thanks.